# Como pegar o nome do usuário remoto conectado ao servidor com java?

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou com um problema que não sei se é possível resolver, estou no desenvolvimento de um sistema intranet e preciso pegar o nome do usuário local(ou seja no pc client).

tentei usar `System.getenv("username")`, que retornou o nome do usuário da maquina do servidor.

Tentei também `request.getRemoteUser()`, `request.getUserPrincipal()`, `request.getAuthType()` e todos eles retornaram `NULL`.

Alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Se é no cliente, não é usuário local, sim, no usuário remoto, a menos que o cliente use a mesma maquina da aplicação.

Comment: Esta resposta no SOEN responde sua pergunta, veja se entende: [How to get the remote user's username in java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25031933/5524514)

Comment: o usuario não vai usar a msm maquina q o sistem está, o sistema se encontra em uma maquina separada que é o servidor

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível, em nenhuma tecnologia, ler diretamente o nome do usuário de um computador remoto. Questão óbvia de segurança. Mesmo que fosse não seria confiável.

Entretanto, se o que você quer é autenticar um usuário logado numa estação, existem mecanismos de Single Sign On (SSO) baseados em diretórios como LDAP que podem resolver o problema, mas não é de trivial implementação e não cabe no escopo desta resposta.

Você pode criar uma outra pergunta contextualizando o cenário que você tem agora e onde exatamente você quer chegar. Uma coisa é certa: recuperar o nome do usuário não é o caminho certo.

Comment: naverdade é exatamente o que eu preciso, preciso saber qual usuario esta logado na estação de cliente, esse sistema roda em rede, uma intranet e queremos fazer a validação pelo usuario q esta logado na maquina para que não seja usado tela de login, para ser mais automático, nunca usei LDAP e SSO, vc teria o link de algum bom tutorial ou artigo sobre essa tecnologia?(vou pesquisar tb, é claro)